# De array X: Si los números están comprendidos entre 0 y 49 a un array1, si números entre 50-100 en arreglo2,si números >101 en arreglo3

Tags: java, array, excepciones

Me sale este error y no entiendo por que. Esa es mi pregunta principal
Output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese la longitud del arreglo: ");
    int n = leer.nextInt();
    double arregloX[] = new double[n];
    int i = 0, ii = 0, iii = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < arregloX.length; a++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero " + (a + 1) + " : ");
        arregloX[a] = leer.nextDouble();
        if (arregloX[a] >= 0 && arregloX[a] <= 49) {
            i++;
        }
        if (arregloX[a] >= 50 && arregloX[a] <= 100) {
            ii++;
        }
        if (arregloX[a] >= 101) {
            iii++;
        }
    }
    double arreglo1[] = new double[i];
    double arreglo2[] = new double[ii];
    double arreglo3[] = new double[iii];
     for (int a = 0,b=0,c=0,d=0; a < arregloX.length; a++,b++,c++,d++) {
         if (arregloX[a] >= 0 && arregloX[a] <= 49) {
            arreglo1[b]=arregloX[a];
        }
        if (arregloX[a] >= 50 && arregloX[a] <= 100) {
            arreglo2[c]=arregloX[a];
        }
        if (arregloX[a] >= 101) {
            arreglo3[d]=arregloX[a];
        }
     } 
}
```

Por favor ayuda con el por que del error. El titulo es para que sepan que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tus variables b, c y d se incrementan hasta llegar al tamaño del arregloX, y si, por ejemplo, el tamaño de arreglo1 es 3, y b es igual 7, al hacer arreglo1[b] habrá un java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Una solución que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la longitud del arreglo: ");
   int n = leer.nextInt();
   double arregloX[] = new double[n];
   int i = 0, ii = 0, iii = 0;
   for (int a = 0; a < arregloX.length; a++) {
      System.out.println("Ingrese el numero " + (a + 1) + " : ");
      arregloX[a] = leer.nextDouble();
      if(arregloX[a] >= 0 && arregloX[a] <= 49) {
         i++;
      }
      if(arregloX[a] >= 50 && arregloX[a] <= 100) {
         ii++;
      }
      if (arregloX[a] >= 101) {
         iii++;
      }
   }
   double arreglo1[] = new double[i];
   double arreglo2[] = new double[ii];
   double arreglo3[] = new double[iii];
   int countArr1 = 0, countArr2 = 0, countArr3 = 0;
   for (int a = 0; a < arregloX.length; a++) {
      if(arregloX[a] >= 0 && arregloX[a] <= 49) {
         arreglo1[countArr1]=arregloX[a];
         countArr1++;
      }
      if(arregloX[a] >= 50 && arregloX[a] <= 100) {
         arreglo2[countArr2]=arregloX[a];
         countArr2++;
      }
      if(arregloX[a] >= 101) {
         arreglo3[countArr3]=arregloX[a];
         countArr3++;
      }
   }
}
```

Recorrer el arregloX y solo si arregloX[a] entra a una de las condiciones se incrementará la variable correspondiente, para guardar el valor de arregloX[a] en la posición indicada de los arreglos